# Numerical integration of a function with singularity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to find the following integral numerically,

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-I*(1- x)*4]*(4)^(1 + 4*I*x)*
  Gamma[epsilon-4*I*x]*(Exp[-2*x*I])/((I*(x - w) + delta)^(1 - 4*I*x)), {x, -Infinity,
   1, Infinity}, Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

Where epsilon and delta are positive numbers and delta and epsilon <<1.

But Mathematica didn't give me any answer. Could you please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: If you add epsilon = 0.01; delta = 0.02; w = 1; before the  NIntegrate command, then you will obtain $ 4.90904\, +3.34651 i$.

Comment: When using Mathematica  numerical functions, you have to specify numerical values for everything.  In this case you have to specify epsilon, delta and w.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I tried to find this integral with larger values of w. But for large w, the result has a deviation from the exact result that I know. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Also, as epsilon and delta get smaller and smaller, the integral doesn't go to a same number and it changes.  Actually, this is the integral I was supposed to do: 
NIntegrate[Exp[-I*(1- x)*4]*(4)^(1 + 4*I*x)*
  Gamma[epsilon-4*I*x]*(Exp[-2*x*I])/((I*(x - w) + delta)^(1 - 4*I*x)), {x, -Infinity,
 , Infinity}]. What is the best method to do this integral, as it has a singularity if w=1 (of course we need to give epsilon and delta some numbers). Can Principal Value a right method? Or I am completely using a wrong method. Thank you so much for your time and consideration.

Comment: Indeed, `Method -> PrincipalValue` is not  a right option here. However, the one does not impair in calculations : the same is produced by `epsilon = 0.01; delta = 0.02; w = 1; NIntegrate[
 Exp[-I*(1 - x)*4]*(4)^(1 + 4*I*x)*
    Gamma[
   epsilon - 
    4*I*x]*(Exp[-2*x*
      I])/((I*(x - w) + delta)^(1 - 4*I*x)), {x, -Infinity,
      Infinity}]`.